# Basic syntax error - KSH

Tags: string, syntax, ksh

I've been debuggin this line for a while, and I'm sure its something simple:

```
370 #Loop through the file looking for any non-required lines
371 { while read myline;do
372 if [[ $myline != "WARN0; 300086; prod_file_stat; Can't find EBCDIC product for PRODUCT_FILE_STATUS;for ASCII 10288" && $myline != "WARN0; 300086; prod_file_stat; Can't find EBCDIC product for PRODUCT_FILE_STATUS;for ASCII 10284" ]]; then
373 echo "ERR: file contains unacceptable errors or warnings! Please double check!"
374 err=1
375 fi
```

I get:

```
  check[50]: syntax error at line 373 : `10284" ]]; then
     echo "ERR:' unexpected
```

Does it have anything to do with the space in the string, or is that a red herring?  Its a KSH script.

Comment: The error suggests mismatched quotes. I don't see anything in the lines you posted, I suspect the problem starts earlier in the script. And notice that the line number is wrong -- "10284" is on 372, but the error message says 373.

Comment: Quote your variables! `"$myline"`

Comment: I've edited it for clarity, and will try it with quotes on the vars

Comment: Have you run it under `ksh -x`?  Why not?

Comment: The problem was indeed higher up in the script, thank you. @JonathanLeffler I have not, because I never knew ksh had a debugging utility. I'm not normally writing ksh scripts, but I will add this to my personal knowledge base.

Comment: There are three separate debugging facilities in most Unix shells, at least those that are derived from the Bourne shell (so the POSIX shells; I'm not sure about the C shells).  They are `-x` (trace as executing), `-v` (print as reading the script), and `-n` (do not actually execute).  `Xsh -nv new-script.sh` will do a syntax check without executing anything, and the output may well help you identify 'blocking errors' where some block is not completed properly (quotes or end keywords, etc).  It makes no sense to combine `-n` and `-x`.

Comment: I’m with Barmar here, it looks like a problem higher up. @vidit quoting the LHS inside [[ … ]] is _not_ necessary and not a good idea either.